# Have I defined all my functions in this app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please could someone help me with the following:

I keep getting the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '8')

```
function addProject(cellAddr) 
{
  var row = String(cellAddr).substring(2);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var finSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("SHEET1");
  var rng = "A" + row + ":DH" + row;
  var headerrng_SHEET2 = "A1:cy1" ;
  var headerrng_SHEET1 = "A2:u2" ;

  var arrVal = sheet.getSheetByName("SHEET1");

  var bArea = arrVal[0][GetColNumber("SHEET2", headerrng_SHEET2, "X/U", "N") -1]; .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error line is the last line in your script? If my understanding is correct, `arrVal` is an object of Class Sheet. In this case, `arrVal[0]` is undefined. And, when `GetColNumber("SHEET2", headerrng_SHEET2, "X/U", "N") -1` is 8, such an error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '8')` occurs. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var arrVal = sheet.getSheetByName("SHEET1");
```

#### To:

```
var arrVal = sheet.getSheetByName("SHEET1").getDataRange().getValues();
```

or, if you want to give a specific range, please modify it as follows.

```
var arrVal = sheet.getSheetByName("SHEET1").getRange("### A1Notation ###").getValues();
```

- Or, you can also use [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) instead of getRange("### A1Notation ###").
- Or, you can also use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of getValues().

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help. This has fixed the error that I was having my script and it now runs, however, it then does not display the values I am looking up from the other sheet at all: eg var bArea = arrVal[0][GetColNumber("SHEET2", headerrng_SHEET2, "X/U", "N") -1];

Comment: @SarahH Thank you for replying. From `Hi, Thank you so much for your help. This has fixed the error that I was having my script and it now runs,`, I understood that your issue was resolved.

Comment: @SarahH About your new issue of `however, it then does not display the values I am looking up from the other sheet at all: eg var bArea = arrVal[0][GetColNumber("SHEET2", headerrng_SHEET2, "X/U", "N") -1];`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot know your function of `GetColNumber` and your Spreadsheet from your question. By this, I cannot propose a modification point. I apologize for this. If you want to resolve your new issue, in this case, more information is required to be provided. Can you provide it?

Comment: @SarahH I noticed your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76521791 In this case, how will you do your this question? Your posted question was resolved. But, about your new question in your reply, can you cooperate to resolve your new question?