# How to create new sheets from multiple tabs

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to create new spreadsheets for all the tabs in my current sheet. I am using the below code but it creates an empty blank "sheet1" and a "copy of tab name" sheet with all the data in my new spreadsheet. How do I get rid of the blank sheet1 and call the "copy of" tab sheet1 please?

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for(var n in ss.getSheets()){
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];// look at every sheet in spreadsheet
    var name = sheet.getName();//get name
      var copy = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);// create the copy
      sheet.copyTo(copy);// copy content
    }
  }
```